# Issues with display FK Data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to display the actual value as opposed to the ID Number using cakePHP.

These are my Tables
[Roles Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJGC5.png)
[Users Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Xd0.png)
l

This is my UsersTable code

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
   public function initialize(array $config)
   {
     $this->hasOne('Roles');
   }
```

This is my UsersController code

```
    public function list()
    { 
       $usersTable = $this->Users->find('all')->contain(['Roles']);
       $allUsers = $usersTable->toArray();

       $this->set("allUsers", $allUsers);
    }
```

This is how im trying to print it

```
$user->role->name
```

However I am getting the following error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NJDH.png)

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this issues?

Comment: In your Roles table, what's the name of the field that references to the Users table ?

Comment: There is no reference in the Roles table. There is a reference in the Users table though which is the role_id

Answer (score 1):

In your UsersTable, the relation order is wrong, it's saying that user has one role, so this will try to join the roles table using a key on the roles table. It should actually be belongsTo, since User belongs to a role. Try this:

```php
class UsersTable extends Table
{
   public function initialize(array $config)
   {
     $this->belongsTo('Roles');
   }
}
```

Comment: Says "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" when I do " $user->role->name"

Comment: What's the output when you dump the $user object ?

Comment: { ["id"]=> int(4) ["name"]=> string(4) "Test" ["surname"]=> string(3) "tet" ["email"]=> string(14) "test@test.test" ["password"]=> string(3) "123" ["role_id"]=> int(2) ["[new]"]=> bool(false) ["[accessible]"]=> array(1) { ["*"]=> bool(true) } ["[dirty]"]=> array(0) { } ["[original]"]=> array(0) { } ["[virtual]"]=> array(0) { } ["[hasErrors]"]=> bool(false) ["[errors]"]=> array(0) { } ["[invalid]"]=> array(0) { } ["[repository]"]=> string(5) "Users" } Var_Dump of a single User